# qsort with structs in C

Tags: c, struct, quicksort, qsort

I have to write a program that uses the qsort function to sort a vector
of points in the Cartesian plane. Each point is formed by a pair of
coordinates (x, y).
Points must be sorted by ascending x-axis.  With the same x-axis,
y-axis is ordered by descending.

This is a sample input:

```
5 (Struct numbers)
2 5
12 2
2 7
3 4
2 2
```

With the output:

```
2 7
2 5
2 2
3 4
12 2
```

Now, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct x_y
{
    int x;
    int y;
}coordinates;
typedef coordinates *coordinatesList;

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    coordinates *a1 = (coordinates *)a;
    coordinates *b1 = (coordinates *)b;
    if (a1->x > b1->x)
        return 1;
    else if (a1->x < b1->x)
        return (-1);
    else if (a1->x == b1->x)
    {
        if (a1->y < b1->y)
            return 1;
        else if (a1->y > b1->y)
            return (-1);
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    coordinatesList *A = (coordinatesList*)malloc(n * sizeof(coordinates));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = (coordinatesList)malloc(sizeof(coordinates));
        scanf("%d%d", &A[i]->x, &A[i]->y);
    }
    qsort(A, n, sizeof(coordinates*), compare);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", A[i]->x, A[i]->y);
    return 0;
}
```

whith his wrong output:

```
2 7
3 4
2 2
2 5
12 2
```

If I try to separate the structs by element:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    coordinates *a1 = (coordinates *)a;
    coordinates *b1 = (coordinates *)b;
    int a_x = a1->x;
    int a_y = a1->y;
    int b_x = b1->x;
    int b_y = b1->y;
    if (a_x > b_x)
        return 1;
    else if (a_x < b_x)
        return (-1);
    else if (a_x == b_x)
    {
        if (a_y < b_y)
            return 1;
        else if (a_y > b_y)
            return (-1);
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

...gives me a different wrong output:

```
2 2
12 2
2 7
3 4
2 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compare function gets pointers to the elements to be sorted, so here it gets pointers to coordinates pointers. The correct beginning is:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const coordinates *a1 = *(const coordinates **)a;
    const coordinates *b1 = *(const coordinates **)b;
```

I added `const` because you shouldn't cast away const-ness, even if it doesn't matter here. You would notice if you used warnings with the compilation.

You should also use `sizeof(coordinates)` in the call to `qsort`, not `sizeof(coordinates*)`, because otherwise the sort function can't know how big your elements are, but these two probably have the same value here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that really solved my problem out!

Answer (score 2):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

In this declaration

```
coordinatesList *A = (coordinatesList*)malloc(n * sizeof(coordinates));
```

you have to use expression `sizeof( coordinatesList )` instead of the expressions `sizeof( coordinates )`.

In the function `compare` you have to write

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const coordinatesList a1 = *( const coordinatesList *)a;
    const coordinatesList b1 = *( const coordinatesList *)b;
    //...
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct x_y
{
    int x;
    int y;
} coordinates;

typedef coordinates *coordinatesList;

int compare( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const coordinatesList a1 = *( const coordinatesList * )a;
    const coordinatesList b1 = *( const coordinatesList * )b;

    if ( a1->x < b1->x )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( b1->x < a1->x )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( a1->y < b1-> y )
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if ( b1->y < a1->y )
        {
            return -1; 
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    coordinatesList *A = malloc( N * sizeof( coordinatesList ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        A[i] = malloc( sizeof( coordinates ) );
    }

    A[0]->x = 2;  A[0]->y = 5;
    A[1]->x = 12; A[1]->y = 2;
    A[2]->x = 2;  A[2]->y = 7;
    A[3]->x = 3;  A[3]->y = 4;
    A[4]->x = 2;  A[4]->y = 2;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\t%d\n", A[i]->x, A[i]->y );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    qsort( A, N, sizeof( coordinatesList ), compare );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\t%d\n", A[i]->x, A[i]->y );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2   5
12  2
2   7
3   4
2   2

2   7
2   5
2   2
3   4
12  2
```